# Swift taking picture crashes

Tags: ios, swift

We have an app and as update we would like to have a Photobooth in the app. Everything works, I get the preview of the camera etc but taking a photo doesn't work.. I have tried all the solutions I found here but nothing works.

head:

```
var captureSession: AVCaptureSession?
var videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
```

draw:

```
do {

        let input = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: getDevice(position: .front))

        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()
        captureSession?.addInput(input)

        videoPreviewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        videoPreviewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        videoPreviewLayer?.frame = cameraView.bounds
        cameraView.layer.addSublayer(videoPreviewLayer!)

        captureSession?.startRunning()
...
```

TakePhoto():

```
let stillImageOutput = AVCaptureStillImageOutput.init()
    stillImageOutput.outputSettings = [AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecJPEG]
    if(self.captureSession?.canAddOutput(stillImageOutput))!{
        self.captureSession?.addOutput(stillImageOutput)
    }

    let videoConnection = stillImageOutput.connection(withMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo)

    if (videoConnection?.isEnabled)! {
        stillImageOutput.captureStillImageAsynchronously(from:videoConnection, completionHandler: {
            (sampleBuffer, error) in
...
```

And it crashes on that last line. Here is the error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '*** -[AVCaptureStillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:completionHandler:] Inconsistent state'
```

Believe it or not, but we need to update our app from Apple within 3 days or it will be removed from the Appstore (we need extra functionality ..) So if you could help us we would be very thankful !

Comment: Just look at my example, I just uploaded it at https://github.com/NikhilManapure/AVFoundationDemo, I hope this helps.

Comment: AVCaptureStillImageOutput is deprecated.  Use AVCapturePhotoOutput instead.

Comment: @NikhilManapure I copied all your code perfectly but I get error : "error occure : Cannot Record" in the capture function, triple checked everything and it's really the same

Answer (score 0):

My best guess (at 5:30 am) is that you haven't requested use of the camera for your app.  Once you have done that, you will need to make sure that your variable  `stillImageOutput` responds to the method `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection` before you attempt to capture a photo.  If it doesn't respond to that method, your user will be required to change his "Settings" to allow you to use the camera.

Comment: I do request it, this is not the problem. But still thank you!